# ¿Como puedo validar el dominio de correo antes de autenticar con google en firebase?

Tags: firebase

Estoy intentando al logearme con google en firebase y que no me cree usuario si el correo no tiene un dominio especifico como @example.com, no se si esto se pueda hacer con las funciones de firebase, no he encontrado un método de autentificacion que haga eso

Answer (score 1):

Lo tendrías que validar con una expresión regular o con una validación manual de la variable con tu cadena de correo, firebase solo te apoya en que sea un correo válido. En la siguiente referencia solo te hace mención al error "auth/invalid-email"
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth.html#createUserWithEmailAndPassword

Este ejemplo es utilizando la validación de cadena:

```
var idx = correo.indexOf('@yahoo.com');
if (idx > -1) {
  // verdadero si contiene yahoo.com
}
```

Referencia del ejemplo:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3270224/5982279